# Ensuring execution in single console application instance

Tags: c#

I have very simple console application that accepts requests based on arguments are, and executes them.

For example:

```
RequestProcessor.exe -RequestType addrequest -RequestInfo "test"
```

It works fine.

What is the best practice(and is it even possible?) to make it so when you execute same command with different arguments, instead of starting another instance of `RequestProcessor.exe`, it just queues the request to existing one if it exists?

From what I understand, I'll need method that creates `Action` based on paramenter values, then add it to action queue, contents of which will be executed asynchroniously, one by one. But how to make it so that all program executions send request to a single queue?

Creating a windows service that accepts such requests seems like one of possible solutions, but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: `It instantly exits, and continues to execute the request in the background` <= Define "exits". How does the application close but still process a request.

Comment: @Igor Sorry, my mistake, I thought it works asynchronously but after closer inspection it turns out it doesn't. Edited question.